# Azure RM Template. Conditinally deploy Copy resource

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-rm

I need to deploy specific resource if there are more than 4 entries in an array parameter. I'm able to do this with 5 (and more) entries, but I also need the deployment not to fail with 3 or less entries, but rather not create that resource at all. Right now I get the following error with 3 or less entries:

> Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation
>   failed: 'The template 'copy' definition at line '56' and column '19'
>   has an invalid copy count. The copy count must be a positive integer
>   value and cannot exceed '800'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for
>   usage details.'.

I tried adding condition to the resource:

```
...
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[greater(length(parameters('apps')),4)]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('apps')[copyIndex(4)].name,'-webtest')]",
...
```

and even:

```
...
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": false,
      "name": "[concat(parameters('apps')[copyIndex(4)].name,'-webtest')]",
...
```

but still getting the same error.
This is the template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "apps": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "value": "111"
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "value": "222"
        },
        {
          "name": "name3",
          "value": "333"
        },
        {
          "name": "name4",
          "value": "444"
        },
        {
          "name": "webtest5",
          "value": "555"
        }
      ]
    },
    "existingApplicationInsightsName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "appname1"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('apps')[copyIndex(4)].name,'-webtest')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/webtests",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('existingApplicationInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "SyntheticMonitorId": "[parameters('apps')[copyIndex(4)].name]",
        "Name": "[parameters('apps')[copyIndex(4)].name]",
        "Enabled": true,
        "Frequency": 300,
        "Timeout": 120,
        "Kind": "ping",
        "RetryEnabled": true,
        "Locations": [
          {
            "Id": "us-ca-sjc-azr"
          }
        ],
        "Configuration": {
          "WebTest": "[concat('<WebTest Name=\"', parameters('apps')[copyIndex(4)].name, '\"',  ' Id=\"', '9d420f1a-f797-427a-804c-f37373eefc82' ,'\"    Enabled=\"True\" CssProjectStructure=\"\" CssIteration=\"\" Timeout=\"0\" WorkItemIds=\"\" xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010\" Description=\"\" CredentialUserName=\"\" CredentialPassword=\"\" PreAuthenticate=\"True\" Proxy=\"default\" StopOnError=\"False\" RecordedResultFile=\"\" ResultsLocale=\"\">        <Items>        <Request Method=\"GET\" Guid=\"a5f10126-e4cd-570d-961c-cea43999a200\" Version=\"1.1\" Url=\"', 'http://www.microsoft.com' ,'\" ThinkTime=\"0\" Timeout=\"300\" ParseDependentRequests=\"True\" FollowRedirects=\"True\" RecordResult=\"True\" Cache=\"False\" ResponseTimeGoal=\"0\" Encoding=\"utf-8\" ExpectedHttpStatusCode=\"', 200 ,'\" ExpectedResponseUrl=\"\" ReportingName=\"\" IgnoreHttpStatusCode=\"False\" /></Items></WebTest>')]"
        }
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "createWebTests",
        "count": "[sub(length(parameters('apps')),4)]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing it like so:

```
"condition": "[greater(length(parameters('apps')),4)]",
```

and set you copy to this:

```
"copy": {
  "name": "createWebTests",
  "count": "[if(greater(length(parameters('apps')),4), sub(length(parameters('apps')),4), 1)]"
}
```

this should work around the fact that in your case count is negative and still not deploy anything when there are less than 4 items in your array

Comment: With your syntax and 3 entries, I get:
`The template resource '[concat(parameters('apps')[copyIndex(4)].name,'-webtest')]' at line '31' and column '9' is not valid: The language expression property array index '4' is out of bounds`
Works with 5 entries though.

Comment: ah right, I think it would make more sense to create nested deployment and condition that (so you dont have to hastle with those problems). or you'd need to put condition on every expression that is using that parameter.

Comment: I think I will used nested deployment indeed. Could you give an example how can I "put condition on every expression that is using that parameter."?
I also wonder why `"condition": "[greater(length(parameters('apps')),4)]",` gets ignored? Documentation for the exact this scenario say "If you need to specify whether a resource is deployed at all, see condition element." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple and I believe that's what we're doing.

Comment: it doesnt get ignored really. arm templates are divided into 2 steps. compilation and implementation. your template fails to compile. conditions only get evaluated at implementation step. so condition wouldn't be able to help you here, unfortunately.

Comment: I ended up using `if` function on every parameter that uses copyIndex. That's what you probably meant by: "you'd need to put condition on every expression that is using that parameter".  `"count": "[if(greater(length(parameters('apps')),4), sub(length(parameters('apps')),4), 1)]"` was the key. Thank you!